# How to Enable File Upload and Insert Image in Android WebView for xenforo forum site

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to build a webview for a xenforo forum site. everything works ok except for "attach file" and "insert image" feature when trying to post in a thread. Please see attched image where I want to enable this feature on the app -> [xf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nszAB.png)

What code (and precisely where please) do I need to add to enable this on the Android Webview.

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.MYAPPNAME">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MYAPPNAME">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.MYAPPNAME;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String websiteURL = "https://www.MYAPPURL.com"; // sets web url
    private WebView webview;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if( ! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this)) //returns true if internet available
        {
            //if there is no internet do this
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection, Chris",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("No internet connection available")
                    .setMessage("Please Check you're Mobile data or Wifi network.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //.setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
        else
        {
            //Webview stuff
            webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());

        }

        //Swipe to refresh functionality
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webview.reload();
                    }
                }
        );

    }


    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        private WebView wv;
        private String url;

        @Override
        //Keep webview in app when clicking links
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                webview.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

    }

    //set back button functionality
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { //if user presses the back button do this
        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) { //check if in webview and the user can go back
            webview.goBack(); //go back in webview
        } else { //do this if the webview cannot go back any further

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("EXIT")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure. You want to close this app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }


}

class CheckNetwork {

    private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(info.isConnected())
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you override [WebChromeClient#onShowFileChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri%5B%5D%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)) method?

To override this method, you also need to override [Activity#onActityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))¹ to get results from [SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) *(or other file select application)*.

```java
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity
{
    //chooser callbak
    private ValueCallback fileCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView web=new WebView(this);
        setContentView(web);
        //set
        web.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChrome());

    }

    
    private class MyWebChrome extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView v, ValueCallback back, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams param) {
            //assign value
            fileCallback=back;
            //launch chooser activity
            //createIntent will automatically set intent parameters for choosing file
            startActivityForResult(param.createIntent(),0);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode!=0||fileCallback==null){
            return;
        }
        //send result, then it's done
        fileCallback.onReceiveValue(
            WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode,data)
        );
        fileCallback=null;
    }
    
}
```

hope it work

---

¹**For [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity?hl=en), prefer using [`registerForActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,%20O%3E,%20androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E))** (I used OnActivityResult because I didn't use AppCompatActivity)